# How to acquire memory ownership from Eigen::Matrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, eigen, eigen3

A dynamically sized `Eigen::Matrix` holds its values in a continuous memory block. I need these values as a memory block I own. I currently copy the values over using `std::memcpy`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
using RowMajorMatrixXf = Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
int main()
{
    RowMajorMatrixXf mat(1024, 2048);
    // ...
    const std::size_t num_bytes = mat.rows() * mat.cols() * sizeof(float);
    float* ptr = (float*)std::malloc(num_bytes); // raw ptr for simplicity
    std::memcpy(ptr, mat.data(), num_bytes);
    // ...
    std::free(ptr);
}
```

However the copying is unnecessary, since the `Eigen::Matrix` is no longer needed at this point. How can I acquire the ownership of the memory of the Eigen Matrix, essentially preventing the Matrix object from freeing the memory in its destructor?

Comment: Is it an option to just keep the "mat" object alive? As it is stack allocated, you need to copy it at least it is goes out of scope. But even if it stays in scope, I see no API to move out the pointer. That is why I ask if keeping the object alive and accessing it is an option?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I also thought about this. But it would mean to drag the Matrix object along through a non-trivial part of the codebase. And I was hoping I could avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

You can better allocate your own buffer, and interpret as an Eigen's matrix using `Map`:

```
float* ptr = new float[r*c];
Map<RowMajorMatrixXf> mat(ptr,r,c);
```

and then use mat just like RowMajorMatrixXf, except its true type is not a RowMajorMatrixXf, so you cannot pass it by reference to a function
taking a `RowMajorMatrixXf&`, for that use `Ref<RowMajorMatrixXf>` or `Ref<const RowMajorMatrixXf>`.

Comment: Make sure the memory buffer is properly aligned for use by Eigen's SIMD optimized functions if you enable these instructions.

Comment: That's not required, Eigen will still vectorize but you might get some small gain if you do so and tell Eigen's the ptr is aligned, e.g.: `Map< RowMajorMatrixXf,Aligned32>`.